# Storing temporary data outside activity lifecycle

Tags: android

I'd like to store some temporary data. Think like storing the `id` of a currently selected conversation in a messaging application.

This could be in a bundle, in a singleton, but I want this to be stored **outside of the activity lifecycle**. This temporary data should behave just parceled data in a view (I just don't want the UI to be responsible for storing this data)

Storing this `id` in memory would work, except this won't survive the system closing the application when memory is low and restoring the application from disk when the user goes back (not sure what the technical term for this is)

`SharedPreferences` would work, except I don't want the data to survive a reboot.

Is there a built in mechanism for this (outside the activity lifecycle)?

Comment: Application level shared preferences

Comment: Do you want the data to survive Activity recreation? What's wrong with the singleton since you seem to be against SharedPreferences? And your messaging application example is unclear. Under what scenario would you keep open the same message thread vs bringing the user to the overall conversations?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes - I want the data to survive activity recreation from disk (like when activities are recreated from low memory situations). but I don't want the data to survive reboots. Essentially I want the functionality of storing `@Parcelable` data in `savedInstanceState` but without being dependent on the UI

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` isn't dependent upon the UI, just the lifecycle. Maybe use SharedPreferences, but clear out the preferences when the app starts

Comment: @cricket_007 can activities be recreated with a non-null `savedInstanceState` when the process is killed by the system (like low memory)? Or are they recreated with state only when the process is still alive?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences...

```
private static final String SHARED_PREFS = "any_name";
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().putInt(key, value).apply();
```

where key can be "current_id" and value would be the ID selected an integer. You can also store a String by using putString() method.

Can easily be accessed as

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.getInt(key, 0);
```

where key would be again "current_id" and 0 is a default value if null is returned.

For more [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) documentation.

If you are going to use the code in Activity you simply can use :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

No need to use context.

Comment: But I don't want this data to survive a reboot, for example

Comment: Ohk, can you explain why?

Comment: think storing which conversation a user has selected in an SMS app. When you reboot the phone and reopen the app, you want the currently selected conversation to be null (no conversation selected)

Comment: If you use the selected id as data required for the coming up activity, you can simply pass the data in an Intent as intent.putExtra("id", id); 
If you have to use the Id within few activities you can create a custom class with getters and setters having just an int id variable and implement Serializable to pass the data.

Comment: If nothing seems proper you can always use a Broadcast receiver to receive the onReboot intent and remove the stored preference. by using  preferences.edit().clear().apply(); the intent will be called when the device reboots.